# How do I install Ubuntu on a PCIE SSD with 2 HDDs in RAID1 for storage?

Tags: server, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I'm typically a PC user, but recently bought the components to make my own server and have decided to run Ubuntu Server. Everything inside of the machine is hooked up now, but I'm unsure of how to properly install Ubuntu on the SSD with storage on the 2 HDDs in RAID1. Where to I begin?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  You have a solid state drive you intend on installing the system too.  Then you have a mechanical disk raid 1 you want to have for file storage?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I would install Ubuntu to the SSD using the 'entire disk' option.  After Ubuntu is installed I would then create your secondary storage mount using fdisk.  Plenty of how-to's on adding a disk.  I prefer to have the /home folder on the SSD for speed, and then create a /mnt/storage for additional storage not requiring constant access.